# What is the filter hook for custom fields content?

Tags: filters, the-content, cubepoints

The following code hides "the_content" output

```
add_filter( "the_content", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" );
function cp_module_pcontent_post_content($content){
        global $post;
        global $cp_module_pcontent_hide;
        if(!in_array($post->ID,(array)$cp_module_pcontent_hide)){
            return $content;
        }
        $c = '<p>' . get_option('cp_module_pcontent_text_pay') . '</p>';
        $c .= apply_filters('cp_module_pcontent_post_content_'.$post->ID, '');
        $c .= '<form method="post">';
        $c .= '<input type="hidden" name="cp_module_pcontent_pay" value="'.$post->ID.'" />';
        $c .= '<p><input type="submit" value="'.get_option('cp_module_pcontent_text_button').'" /></p>';
        $c .= '</form>';
        if(!is_user_logged_in()){
            $c = get_option('cp_module_pcontent_text_logout');
        }
        $c = str_replace('%points%',cp_formatPoints(get_post_meta($post->ID,'cp_pcontent_points', 1)),$c);
        return $c;
    }
```

Check these screenshots.

If the user not logged in it display this

[image]

If the user logged in it display like this

[image]

Please note only `the_content` output is hidden

Here is my problem. I'm using magic fields plugin. It is a plugin to create custom fields.

For example this is the code my single.php file using.

```
    <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

 <!-- magic fields plugin code starts -->
    <div class="custom-content">
            <?php if (function_exists('get_field')) { 
                    $requirements = get_field('requirements_requirements');
                        if($requirements){  
                            foreach($requirements as $requirement){
                            echo $requirement;
                            } 
                        } 
                    } ?>

    </div>
  <!-- magic fields plugin code ends -->
```

Magic fields plugin output are not hidden here
I want to hide those Magic fields plugin output instead of `the_content` output. I mean `requirements` instead of `the_content`.

When i replace "the_content" with "the_title" it hides the title.

For example like this

add_filter( "the_title", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" );  //hides title

add_filter( "the_tags", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" );  //hides tags

add_filter( "wp_list_categories", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" ); //hides categories

add_filter( "???????", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" );  //hides magic fields group

To hide those requirements I need to replace

```
add_filter( "the_content", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" );
```

to

```
add_filter( "xxxxxxxx", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" );
```

Can you tell me what is that `xxxxxxxx`?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you can just attach the same filter to multiple hooks, generally one hook is not the same as the next and what you're showing above is re-using the same function(which i'm surprised works). The main thing you need to know appears to be finding a suitable hook in the [magic fields plugin](http://svn.wp-plugins.org/magic-fields/trunk/). I don't know the plugin nor am i searching through all those files to find hooks(sorry you're on your own there).

Comment: No i'm not using same filter to multiple hooks, I just given some examples that it worked when i replace `the_content` with `the_title / the_tags / wp_list_categories`. And one more thing my first code snippet is found in cubepoints plugin. This is the [full snippet code](http://pastebin.com/MqgdJj6m)

Comment: @t31os How to award my 50 reputation to you? I [answered myself](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36390/5074) with the help of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found the answer. Thanks to @t31os and [his code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36367/some-questions-regarding-filter/36368#36368).

This is what i did.

Replaced this line

```
echo $requirement;
```

with

```
echo apply_filters('requirement','$requirement');
```

And then again I replaced this first line

```
add_filter( "the_content", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" );
```

with

```
add_filter( "requirement", "cp_module_pcontent_post_content" );
```

Voila its working perfectly now. :)

Comment: Still not quite sure what you were aiming, just happy to hear you reached a solution, and i'm happy to have helped all the same.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since custom fields are kept in the meta table, you can proabably just remove this line:

```
 $c = str_replace('%points%',cp_formatPoints(get_post_meta($post->ID,'cp_pcontent_points', 1)),$c);
```

Alternatively, you can use a boolean as a parameter to not run this line of code.

HTH