# Some questions regarding filter

Tags: filters

1) Take a look at this example

```
add_filter( "xxx_xxxxx", "blah_blah" );
function blah_blah(){
        echo "filter added";
    }
```

`xxx_xxxxx` can be anything like my_filter or it should be one of the name [listed here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

2) Lets say i have some content in my theme outside `the_content` loop.

Example

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-content">
                <p>Blah blah some text goes here</p>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Is there a way to filter `Blah blah some text goes here` text?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether you're trying to hook to an existing filter or hook to one you've made, looking at your second code sample suggests you're asking about making your own filter.

And, yes you can add your own, something like this is valid inside your loop.

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'my_blah_filter', '<p>Blah blah some text goes here</p>' ); ?>
```

You can then hook that filter, as you would with regular WordPress filters, eg.

```
add_filter( 'my_blah_filter', 'my_filter_for_blah' );
function my_filter_for_blah( $filter_content ) {
    // Uncomment the next line to see the effect of not replacing it
    $filter_content = 'new content';
    return $filter_content;
}
add_filter( 'my_blah_filter', 'wpautop' );
```

Let me know if that helps. :)

Comment: Yes very helpful. Can you apply your answer to [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35983/what-is-the-filter-hook-for-custom-fields-content)? I asked this question just to understand how it works. So it would be awesome if you can spend some more time to give me the solution. Thanks

Comment: Sorry i don't follow your other question, i'm really not sure what i'm seeing and what you're aiming to do there, it's just not clear to me.

Comment: Bro i updated my question with screenshots. I explained as much as i can. Please check that page now. Thanks

Comment: @t31os Hope you don't mind the edit - else maybe paragraph inside paragraphs would appear. :)

Comment: As much as i appreciate the update kaiser, seeing as the asker is new to filters it may only make things more confusing, appreciate your ingenuity all the same.

Comment: @kaiser Could you please tell me why you added this line? `add_filter( 'my_blah_filter', 'wpautop' );`

Comment: @Viruthagiri that filters the output with the wpautop function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop), which automatically adds paragraph tags. He edited the example to use that instead of including paragraph tags in the new content, since it's possible that could get filtered with wpautop anyway, and would thus result in nested paragraphs. kaiser's method avoids this possibility.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I finally found the solution using @t31os code. t31os could you please tell me how to award my 50 reputation to you for [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35983/what-is-the-filter-hook-for-custom-fields-content)